# How do I use vue-resource v-links inside a vueify component?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

When using `v-link="{ path: '/add' }"` in my vueify (used with Laravel) component, I get a `v-link can only be used inside a router-enabled app.` or a `<router-view> can only be used inside a router-enabled app.` error.

Here is my main.js: http://laravel.io/bin/Kkj27

My code seems very similar to the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/naeg67da/) provided for nestedRoutes, I am not sure why this is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all a little confusing to me (best practices for structuring Vue.js single page apps) but this is essentially what I did to make it work:

```
Vue.component('Todo', Todo);
```

And removing this whole thing:

```
var TodoApp = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    components: { Todo }
});
```

After this, I can refer to the `Todo` component in the `router.map` function.

```
router.map({
    '/': {
        component: Todo,
        subRoutes: {

            '/bar': {
             ...
            },
            '/baz': {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
})
```